# Is it possible to have "dynamic" function pointer in rebol?

Tags: rebol, red

I can create p as a pointer to f like this:

```
f: func[][print 1]
p: :f
```

When executing:

```
>> p
1
```

But if I modify f to

```
f: func[][print 1 print 2]
```

p won't print 2.

Is there another way to get p points "dynamically" to f ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note you've created a new instance of f there - not modified it. You can modify f though by altering the contents of its second block. ie...

```
>> f: func[][print 1]
>> p: :f
>> p
1
>> append second :f [print 2]
== [print 1 print 2]
>> p
1
2
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: In R3 it *is* possible to modify functions if you can access the original body of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an **alias**.

Alias in REBOL is a little limited as you cannot use any pre-existing word as an alias. But this works for me:

```
f: does [print 1]    ;; define 'f as you do
alias 'f "px"        ;; create an alias as 'px
px 
== 1                 ;; same result as 'f

f: context [a: 3]    ;; change 'f to something completely different
probe px             ;; 'px is the same as the new 'f
    make object! [
        a: 3
    ]
```

Comment: I love alias very much but many times it's very buggy often it pretends that there is already an alias for the string whereas it isn't true.

Comment: Hope alias works better in rebol 3 but I remember carl wanted to drop it down for the very reason he knows it's buggy

Answer (score 0):

when you do F: :P you are actually doing F "points to" P's *value* (the function).

when you do P: func [][]  again, you are creating a new function *value* to which only P is assigned the value.

the only way to have indirection is via an accessor, something like F: does [P]

when p changes *value* f will know to call the new function since the binding of P has not changed, only its value (which is a new function).

alias are word equivalencies, not pointers, so they are also valid as words on paths and are quite nasty in real world use.